# ros2 run .. --ros-args is not working

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Whenever I run: `ros2 run package_name executable_name --ros-args -p param_name:=param_value`
and in another terminal: `ros2 param get /node_name param_name` I get: **Parameter not set**.

If in the code I try to: `this->declare_parameter("param_name");` and then do the run as above, the execution stops immediately.

What I need to do is to pass a parameter from the CLI and read it in the code. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** to answer @ljaniec comment,
I want to run something like:

```
ros2 run pkg_name exe_name --ros-args "string:=aa"
```

So I put in the code:

```
std::string string;
this->declare_parameter<std::string>("string", std::string("no"));      
this->get_parameter_or("string", string, std::string("no"));
std::cout << string<< "\n";
```

Now reading [this](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html), a string should be passed as:
`--ros-args "string:=aa`", I also tried other combinations:
`--ros-args string:="aa"` or `--ros-args string:=aa`, but none works. The execution starts and stops without saying anything.
(I don't have problems with int).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404776/ros2-run-..---ros-args-is-not-working/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2022-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-09**:
Can you provide a minimal "should-be-working" example? I think it will be the easiest way for us to help you

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-09**:
I can see that you are using `std::string`, try to change it to `string` (as [here](https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html#supported-datatypes)). Maybe change the name of the parameter from `"string"` to `"my_string"`` as well, because it is a special name in ROS (datatype).

[This tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html#parameters) shows example CLI with setting the string parameters (changed for clarity):

`ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp parameter_blackboard --ros-args -p "a_string:=Hello world"`

It seems you missed the `-p` in your `--ros-args "string:=aa"` - it should be rather `--ros-args -p "my_string:=aa"`

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-08-09**:
Yes I forgot the `-p` here, but I was using it in the CLI. Also, the param name was only an example, so in the code I'm not using "string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to make it work with an **int** parameter. This is what I did:

```
int n;
this->declare_parameter<int>("param", 0);
this->get_parameter_or("param", n, 0);
```

And then use: `ros2 run pkg_name exe_name --ros-args param:=1`.

So it was important to specify the **parameter type**.

Nevertheless, I had a problem with **string** parameters, so I surrounded the 2 functions with a `try-catch`:

```
try {
    this->declare_parameter<std::string>("calib", "no");
    this->get_parameter_or("calib", calib, std::string("no"));
}
catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

And I found out a **strange behaviour**: if I use

```
ros2 run pkg_name exe_name --ros-args -p "calib:=yes"
```

I get an **exception** that says: parameter `'calib'` **has invalid type: expected [string] got [bool]**.

While using something else

```
ros2 run pkg_name exe_name --ros-args -p "calib:=ok"
```

The param is read correctly.

So it seems that **true**, **false**, **yes** and **no** are recognised as `bool`. In fact, using:

```
try {
    this->declare_parameter<bool>("calib", false);
    this->get_parameter_or("calib", calib, false);
}
catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

I can run correctly: `ros2 run pkg_name exe_name --ros-args -p "calib:=yes"`, while having the inverse exception with `"calib:=ok"` .

---

Originally posted by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) with karma: 100 on 2022-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-09**:
In ROS2 [you have `string`  as a datatype](https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html#supported-datatypes), not C++ `std::string`

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-08-09**:
Mmh this should be the solution, but I receive some compiler error using `this->declare_parameter<string>(.., ..);`:

error C2065: 'string': **undeclared identifier**.

Moreover, the behaviour is strange, in fact to declare an int param I should use `int64`, but I only use `int`.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-09**:
Ok, I misled you, this [example](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-CPP.html#write-the-c-node) uses `std::string` so it shouldn't be that. Your last remark about `yes` and `ok` being booleans are surprising for sure! I didn't find any mention of this [here](https://design.ros2.org/articles/interface_definition.html) nor [here](https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html#supported-datatypes). Maybe it is worth filling out the issue in the `rclcpp` repository?

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-08-09**:
Yes, I think I'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since Dashing, you need to first declare a parameter before getting or setting it. If you try to get or set an undeclared parameter you will either get an exception thrown, e.g. `ParameterNotDeclaredException`, or in certain cases you will get an unsuccessful result communicated in a variety of ways (see specific functions for more details).

May I request you to read the documentation at the following URL:

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Releases/Release-Dashing-Diademata.html#getting-and-setting-undeclared-parameters

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1